# Rendering partial for nested object not processing object nor locals

Tags: ruby-on-rails

An enumeration of objects, has nested objects.  The goal is to render a partial for futher nested objects

```
<% groups.each do |group| %>
  <% group.children.each do |child| %>
    <% if child.lessons.size > 0 %>
      <% render 'child_partial' %>
    <% end %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When the partial is defined as [as per the Rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables)

```
<% render 'child_partial', locals: {child: child} %>
```

or

```
<% render 'child_partial', object:  child %>
```

error `undefined local variable or method 'child' for #<ActionView::Base` is returned when the partial calls (for testing purposes)  `<%= child.class %>`

How can I pass the object to the partial so that it may be processed properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to follow the guides literally:

```rb
<%= render partial: 'child_partial', locals: {child: child} %> # or
<%= render 'child_partial', child: child %>
```

And it's better to render with [collections](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) for performance:

```rb
<% groups.each do |group| %>
  <%= render partial: 'child_partial',
             collections: group.children.select { |child| child.lessons.size > 0 },
             as: :child %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

`render` will not accept additional local variables for the partial, you need to use `render partial:` as following for that:

```
<% render partial: 'child_partial', locals: {child: child} %>
```